# An improper integral question

Tags: improper-integrals

everyone who is interested calculus, I wonder ask a question about the value of an improper integral. Here is the integral:
$\int_0^\infty \! \frac{e^{-x}}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x $

Is it diverge ( how to proof it's divergence ), or converge ( how to find it's value )?

Thank you guys if you can help me for this! :)

Comment: This diverges due to the divergent behavior of $\frac{1}{x}$ around the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, $\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx$ diverges since on $[0,1]$ we have $e^{-x} > \frac{1}{e}$ and $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\,dx$ diverges.

Comment: Wow, get it~! Thanks! 
How about... if I change e^{-x} to e^{x} ?

Comment: Well, in that case $\frac{e^x}{x} \ge \frac{1}{x}$, so again it diverges.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll accept it several minutes later. 
( It shows that I can't accept an answer in 6 minutes... )